# Geyser support for events?

Tags: anchor, geyser

does https://docs.solana.com/validator/geyser also allow a user to parse events?

I'm researching whether it is worth the trouble integrating such a plugin for my app.

Trying to get an understanding of what data it allows me to parse and store in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a formal specification for "events" in Solana at the protocol level, but typically they're structured logs emitted by programs.

In that sense, you can create a handler for `notify_transaction` which reads through the logs in the provided transaction: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/056930483531424f2ef584be8aeaa1cee56b0db7/geyser-plugin-interface/src/geyser_plugin_interface.rs#L401

If you receive the logs from every single transaction processed by the network, you can filter out the transactions that contain the log or "event" that you care about.

Comment: got it - thanks! and just for my understanding, for me to use geyser plugins, i'll need to spin up my own validators right? for devnet and mainnet? `notify_transaction` looks like what i need, just gonna keep reading some tutorials to get up to speed

Comment: Correct, you'll need some direct connection to a running validator, one for each network that you want to monitor. You could run the validator, or maybe you can convince an operator to compile your geyer plugin into their validator, if you have a good relationship with one of them